# Older questions and fewer views

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, answers

I noticed that at the time [Aviation Beta](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/) started (second half of December 2013), many great questions were asked, but they got very little attention because this forum didn't have many users at that time.

Although many of those questions have already selected an answer, should there be a way to bring them again to limelight since the user base has enhanced exponentially.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ultimate design goals of the site are still constrained by its Stack Overflow heritage: It's a system designed to answer the current questions being asked, and floating old questions back to the front page regularly tends to interfere with that.

Popularity inherently falls off as questions age, and even our best early questions are unfortunately in the "long tail" now (with apologies to [Chris Anderson](http://www.thelongtail.com/about.html)).
[image: Long Tail graphic]
Theoretically if people are interested in the content of older questions they can find them - Google likes us.

---

There are two exceptions to this:

1. If these questions are edited or get a new answer they will be "active" which will bring them back to the default front page. (If there is no real reason to edit the question editing them just for "bumps" is a Bad Thing, but if they can be improved by all means improve them!)
2. Unanswered questions will sometimes be "bumped" by the community user automatically.
   That's designed so a question with no upvoted or accepted answers will eventually find its way back to the front page and hopefully get an answer.

Comment: I would add that if someone thinks that one of these questions could perhaps get better answers with additional attention, they can also offer a bounty on it!

Comment: @Lnafziger Yup - I forgot all about bounties - those are great incentives for new users to answer other new users' questions. (Slightly less effective on higher-rep users, but sometimes they still work)

Comment: @voretaq7 The graph makes sense, and probably is true for many other things too. For the questions I asked early on, I have selected an answer because there weren't many answers at all. It is the past though.

Comment: I know about bounties but I'm not as rich as you guys.

Comment: @Farhan If you are unhappy with the quality of answer that you have on an old post and think that you may get better answers now, you can always unaccept the answer and edit the question to clarify what you are still looking for.

Comment: @Farhan Hey!  I didn't mean for you to unaccept **MY** answers, lol!  ;-)

Comment: @Lnafziger I didn't want to and it was breaking my heart. I also noticed that no one has ever done that. But your suggestion helped me make the decision.

Comment: @Lnafziger BTW, chances are no one can come up with a better answer than yours. ;)